# Printing bulk reports in crystal report programmatically using vb.net and sql server

Tags: sql-server-2012, crystal-reports

Please I am working on a School management system in vb.net and will like to print all the reports of students in a particular class in bulk at the same time programmatically. What I have done so far is, I select all the students IDs of a particular class from the studentstb which is the master table and fill the DataTable with it. I now iterate through the items using a for loop.
The bulk printing seams to work but the ranking which should have been base on a class is now repeating itself to display multiple subjects for one student.
If the number of subjects the student registered are six, it is repeating the six subjects to display about 18 of the same subjects.

Below is the code I have written:

```
Public Sub printbulk()


    If mysqlconnectionstring.State = ConnectionState.Broken Then
        mysqlconnectionstring.Open()
    End If

rem instance of the crystal report
    Dim rpt As CrystalReportbulkreport = New CrystalReportbulkreport

rem instance of the dataset and dataAdapter to fill the dataset for the crystal report
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim da1 As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dar As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim atten As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim bi As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim b As New SqlDataAdapter

Dim strclass As String = bclasss.Text
Dim strterm As String = termc.Text
Dim sess As String = sessionb.Text



rem open a printer dialogue

    Me.PrintDialogbulk.Document = Me.PrintDocumentbulk

    Dim dr = Me.PrintDialogbulk.ShowDialog()
if dr = DialogResult.OK then


    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim df As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim strid As String

    Dim strget As String = "select studentid from studentstb where stuclass='" & strclass & "'"
    df.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(strget, mysqlconnectionstring)
    df.Fill(dt)

    rem iterate throuh the dataTable studentid
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        For Each coll As DataColumn In dt.Columns


            strid = row("studentid")

    rem get the students rank in class plus some other info from assessment table
            rem get student position in exam 
            Dim str1 As String = " SELECT * FROM (SELECT studentid,stuname,session,f_score,stuclass,term,subject,final_ca,final_exam,ca,exam_score,remarks,f_scores = SUM(f_score),position = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(f_score) desc) FROM assessment WHERE stuclass = '" & strclass & "' and term='" & strterm & "' and session='" & sess & "' GROUP BY studentid,f_score,stuclass,term,subject,final_ca,final_exam,ca,exam_score,stuname,session,remarks) T WHERE  studentid = '" & strid & "' "


            da.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(str1, mysqlconnectionstring)

        rem get student remarks & conduct from the remarks table
            Dim strr As String = "select class_attendance,conduct,interest,promoted_to,cremarks from remarks where studentid='" & strid & "' and stuclass='" & strclass & "' and  term='" & strterm & "' and session='" & sess & "' "
            dar.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(strr, mysqlconnectionstring)

        rem get  student pic
            Dim str11 As String = "select studentid,photo from studentstb where stuclass='" & strclass & "' and studentid='" & strid & "' "

            da1.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(str11, mysqlconnectionstring)


        rem get student attendance 
            Dim stratten = "select attendance,reopen from attendance1 where term ='" & strterm & "' and session ='" & sess & "' "

            atten.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(stratten, mysqlconnectionstring)


        rem get student bill from takehomebill table

            Dim h = "select studentid,sum(amt_topay) as amt_topay from takehomebill where class='" & strclass & "' and lodging=(select lodging from studentstb where studentid='" & strid & "') group by studentid "

            bi.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(h, mysqlconnectionstring)

        rem fil the datasets with the various dataAdapters
            dar.Fill(ds, "remarks")
            da.Fill(ds, "assessment")
            da1.Fill(ds, "studentstb")
            atten.Fill(ds, "attendance1")
            bi.Fill(ds, "takehomebill")

    rem Assign the print to the crystap report
            rpt.SetDataSource(ds)
            rpt.SetParameterValue("c1", strclass)
            rpt.SetParameterValue("c2", strid)
            rpt.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 0, 0)


        Next
    Next


    end if

    mysqlconnectionstring.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi lotwan, thanks for using the self answered question format to share your knowledge with the community. This post could use some improvement in its formatting though. I recommend adding the VB.NET tag to make it easier for readers to find your post (it will also enable syntax highlighting). In addition to this, the text above your post could use some grammar improvements, and it could also be formatted better to improve readability, instead of just being a single paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by inserting a group into the crystal report. I used the studentid as the group name. I checked insert new page after the group footer.
Thank you.